# Standing Instruction Execution in a Batch Process in different streams

Tags: java

To answer this question needs a bit of Banking knowledge :

Say I had setup SI from account a1->a2 and a2->a3
These are only two instructions, which needs to be processed in a batch.
But I want that these two instructions will be processed in two different streams.

Which is not possible, as the account a2 is locked in stream 1 and cannot be processed in stream 2, till the stream 1 finished its processing.

A work around to this problem:
Either I execute all SI's in one stream or I identify the dependency of instructions and put these instructions into stream accordingly.

Or is there any other way around to work on this.

I am using Java and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of your problem, but it sounds a lot like [data hazards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29#Eliminating_hazards) in pipeline CPUs.

In your case you want to maximize the utilization of your functional units (streams) without introducing data hazards. Maybe you can write a simple scheduler that looks ahead into the next n instructions and schedules them on to streams?

```
/**
 * Keeps track of which stream is scheduled to process each account.
 * If an account is not currently scheduled to be processed, it doesn't appear in the keySet of this map.
 */
Map<Account, Stream> accountsInFlight; // use a synchronized implementation

void schedule(Instruction instruction) {
  // If the input account is in flight somewhere, use that stream
  if (accountsInFlight.containsKey(instruction.getInAccount())) {
    scheduleToStream(instruction, accountsInFlight.get(instruction.getInAccount()));

  // If the output account is in flight somewhere, use that stream
  } else if (accountsInFlight.containsKey(instruction.getOutAccount())) {
    scheduleToStream(instruction, accountsInFlight.get(instruction.getOutAccount()));

  // If neither are in flight, this is a good candidate for parallel execution, 
  // put it in a different stream
  } else {
    Stream stream = // pick a stream (maybe the one with the shortest queue?)
    scheduleToStream(instruction, stream);
  }
}

private void scheduleToStream(Instruction instruction, Stream stream) {
  stream.addToQueue(instruction);
  // Update accountsInFlight
  accountsInFlight.put(instruction.getInAccount(), stream);
  accountsInFlight.put(instruction.getOutAccount(), stream);
}

// Remove accounts from the map when the instruction completes
```

Note that this is all fake code: it's not optimized nor does it cover all cases correctly, but maybe it'll give you some ideas to get started.